# Python tkinter for loop not displaying correcty

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter, pycharm

Making a blackjack game and this for loop is not printing the correct cards. It prints the first card and second card fine, but when it gets to the third card it reprints the first card instead in the third one's place. I have tried both deleting and not deleting the images before print but it doesn't work out.

```
if len(playerCards) > 0:  
    for i in range(len(playerCards)):  
        #print(currentHand[i])  
        #print currentHand  
        #print(i)  
        #print(playerCards[i])  
        GAME_CANVAS._tkcanvas.delete("pCard" + str(i))  
        GAME_CANVAS._tkcanvas.create_image(125+((i-1)*80), 75, image = playerCards[i].image, tag = "pCard" + str(i))
```

I have the current print statements commented because they should not affect the code in any way.

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong with the `tkinter` part of your program, but I can tell you that your loop could be _much_ simpler, by using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).  Replace the first two lines with `for i, card in enumerate(PlayerCards):`, and then use `card` instead of `playerCards[i]` inside the loop.  That saves you one layer of indentation, and (potentially) a lot of `[]` indexing inside the loop.

Comment: Only the last image in playerCards will acturally show.  The for loop will go through all of the cards so fast that you won't be able to see them displayed and then deleted on the next pass through the loop.  Not enough info here to really help so just guessing, but if the "first card" is the last card in playerCards on the first and third times this loop is called, then it will be displayed twice.